# too many try catch in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

I'm working on server-side using TypeScript. And I got a question.
using jwt, I have to catch several types of error.
But each line has their own custom error to be sent to client. That means each line has their own try-catch clause. It look not cool. and I don't know it is good practice or not.(I'm 60% sure that it might not good...)

Example:

```
try {
  dowork();
} catch(err) {
  throw NouserError;
}

try {
  dowork2();
} catch(err) {
  throw InvalidTokenError;
}

try {
  dowork3();
} catch(err) {
  throw blablaError();
}

...and more and more...
```

I'm thinking of converting like the below. By move `try-catch` block inside the functions, functions don't return the its result when errors occur.
Suggested:

```
const val1 = dowork();
if(!val1) {
   throw NouserError;
}

const val2 = dowork2();
if(!val2) {
   throw InvalidTokenError;
}

const val3 = dowork3();
if(!val3) {
   throw blablaError();
}

...and more and more...
```

But I have no sure that My suggested idea is good or terrible. definitely, the original one is something wrong. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own exceptions, and throw them when needed, and use only one try() and check the type of the exception

```
try {
  myroutine(); // may throw three types of exceptions
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
  } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
    // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
  } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
    // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
  } else {
    // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
    logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function to fetch your data i think

```
export async function fetchRetry(url: string, options: any) {
  let error = null;
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const { status } = response;
      if (response.ok) {
        try {
          return await response.json();
        } catch (error) {
          // for response that has no body to parse like DELETE method
          return true;
        }
      }
      if (status === 406) {
        error = new ObsoleteApiError("API Deprecated");
      }

      if (status === 503) {
        error = new MaintenanceApiError("We are currently undergoing maintenance");
      }

      if (status >= 400 && status < 500) {
        // code to log to flurry
        if (status === 400) {
            error = new BadRequestError('Bad Request Error')
        }
        error = new ClientApiError(
          `Invalid input on :${url}`,
          await response.json()
        );
      }

      if (status === 403 || status === 401) {
        error = new SingleSessionError("You have logged into another device");
        await AccessToken.getNewTokens();
      }

      break;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (!error) {
        console.log(`request error based on url: ${url}`);
        console.log(err.name);
        error = err;
      }
    }
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  throw new ServerApiError("Server error");
}
```

then you only call

```
const {data} = fetchRetry("http://blabla", options)
```